# Mosaic layout with angular material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm wodering if it's possible to make a mozaic layout with angular material. What I want to do is to display section differently depending on section count. For example if I have 3 sections to dispay it would be something like

```
Section1 Section2 Section3
```

for 4 sections it would be like

```
Section1 Section2 
Section3 Section4
```

I couldn't find any examples for this. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at *Layout* and further information of Angular Material: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction It's often done (in normal CSS) with *flexbox* and *:nth-child*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining the `flex` directive on each of the elements as defined in the [layout documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction) for Angular Material.

To achieve the layout defined in the question, you could use the directives in this manner:

```
<div layout="row" layout-sm="column">
  <div flex>Section 1</div>
  <div flex>Section 2</div>
</div>

<div layout="row" layout-sm="column">
  <div flex>Section 3</div>
  <div flex>Section 4</div>
</div>
```